# Invalid thread operation, Invoke method does not work

Tags: c#

I have an online chat code, there is a list of logged in users on the system. There is a problem adding the users name in the `listBox`; The error is as follows: `Invalid thread operation: control 'lbClients' accessed from a thread that is not the one in which it was created.`

I tried the `Invoke` method, but it also did not work. With the `Invoke` method, the server adds the user to the list, but when the user disconnects, the list of users logged on to the server does not refresh. What can be done?

```
public void ServiceClient()
    {
        Socket client = clientsocket;
        bool keepalive = true;

        while (keepalive)
        {
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
            client.Receive(buffer);
            string clientcommand = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

            string[] tokens = clientcommand.Split(new Char[]{'|'});
            Console.WriteLine(clientcommand);

            if (tokens[0] == "CONN")
            {
                for(int n=0; n<clients.Count; n++) {
                    Client cl = (Client)clients[n];
                    SendToClient(cl, "JOIN|" + tokens[1]);
                }
                EndPoint ep = client.RemoteEndPoint;
                //string add = ep.ToString();
                Client c = new Client(tokens[1], ep, clientservice, client);
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => clients.Add(c)));
                string message = "LIST|" + GetChatterList() +"\r\n";
                SendToClient(c, message);
                try
                {
                    lbClients.Items.Add(c);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }

            }
            else if (tokens[0] == "CHAT")
            {
                for(int n=0; n<clients.Count; n++)
                {
                    Client cl = (Client)clients[n];
                    SendToClient(cl, clientcommand);
                }
            }
            else if (tokens[0] == "PRIV")
            {
                string destclient = tokens[3];
                for(int n=0; n<clients.Count; n++) {
                    Client cl = (Client)clients[n];
                    if(cl.Name.CompareTo(tokens[3]) == 0)
                        SendToClient(cl, clientcommand);
                    if(cl.Name.CompareTo(tokens[1]) == 0)
                        SendToClient(cl, clientcommand);
                }
            }
            else if (tokens[0] == "GONE")
            {
                int remove = 0;
                bool found = false;
                int c = clients.Count;
                for(int n=0; n<c; n++)
                {
                    Client cl = (Client)clients[n];
                    SendToClient(cl, clientcommand);
                    if(cl.Name.CompareTo(tokens[1]) == 0)
                    {
                        remove = n;
                        found = true;
                        lbClients.Items.Remove(cl);
                        //lbClients.Items.Remove(cl.Name + " : " + cl.Host.ToString());
                    }
                }
                if(found)
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => clients.RemoveAt(remove)));
                client.Close();
                keepalive = false;
            }
            else
            {
                int remove = 0;
                bool found = false;
                int c = clients.Count;
                for (int n = 0; n < c; n++)
                {
                    Client cl = (Client)clients[n];
                    //SendToClient(cl, clientcommand);
                    if (cl.Name.CompareTo(tokens[1]) == 0)
                    {
                        remove = n;
                        found = true;
                        lbClients.Items.Remove(cl);
                        //lbClients.Items.Remove(cl.Name + " : " + cl.Host.ToString());
                    }
                }
                if (found)
                    clients.RemoveAt(remove);
                client.Close();
                keepalive = false;
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This is not C code.  C# or Java maybe?

Comment: It's not Java, but multiple signs point to C#.

Comment: Which line produces the error?
And could you please post the code you tried with the Invoke()?

Comment: @Metheny No row displays error, but `listbox` does not refresh by deleting the disconnected user.

Comment: @dbush this is one C# code

Comment: @Marlon: In your original post you mentioned an error occurs. In which line *of code* does this happen?

Comment: @Metheny I tried several endpoints in the code, however it does not return error, but the `this.Invoke(new Action(() => lbClients.Items.Remove(cl)));` is not fired after the user disconnects. Remembering that the user is inserted in the list by the excerpt: `this.Invoke(new Action(() => lbClients.Items.Add(c)));` in the code I tried.

Comment: @Metheny Sorry, I missed, The error is: Invalid thread operation: control 'lbClients' accessed from a thread that is not the one in which it was created. At the line: `lbClients.Items.Add(c);`

Comment: Obviously, you run this method on a separate thread. Therefore, you must use `Invoke` to access all gui controls. In particular, to `lbClients`. For example you don't use `Invoke` inside `try` block.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov So i need to use invoke for all lbclients modifications?